The Stacks Editor messes up code formatting
I’ve started a new question on Stack Overflow and the Wizard form was shown to me.  This uses the Stacks Editor.
When I use the code icon to format blocks of code, it adds single back-ticks instead of triple back-ticks, which loses all indentation and new lines inside of the block.
Makyen commented:

[It] is a known issue, which was first reported quite some time ago. I'm unsure how long ago for that particular issue, but I'd expect at least a year. The Stacks Editor which SE has insisted on using in the Question Wizard has had problems, including with code, from its inception about 4.5 years ago. While some issues have been fixed, SE has declined to fix it sufficiently for it to be reasonably used, yet they have forced its use in a variety of places .

But I haven’t found that specific question, so I’m creating this one.
The question was split from  Issues with the “Question Wizard” as it is recommended to keep one issue per question.

In the Stacks Editor, there are actually two buttons/icons for formatting code:


Inline code (Cmd+K)
Single line code span for use within a block of text.
(This inserts single backticks.)


Code block (Cmd+M)
Multiline block of code with syntax highlighting.
(This inserts triple backticks.)



Heh, and they claim they try to help beginners, LOL. This cant' be more confusing. Especially for people who are already used to CTRL+K being code block, not inline code.

@ShadowWizard and for people who are already used to the second icon being for snippets.

And for people who are already used to Ctrl+K being used to access the search bar.
